# How to utilize SelectedItem within LoadingRow Eventhandler of DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, datagrid

I would like simply set the selectedItem of the Datagrid to the incoming loadingRow.
I tried this:

```
private void call_dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
      if (((Call) e.Row.DataContext).HasValidationErrors)
      {
          call_dataGrid.SelectedItem = (Call)e.Row.DataContext;

      }
}
```

It definitely hits the assignment. But nothing happens.  If I run the same code from a button's on click eventhandler, it works perfectly fine.  Despite the documentation claiming :

> Occurs after a DataGridRow is instantiated, so that you can customize
>   it before it is used.

I think as long as the row is not rendered, I wont be able to select it within the dataGrid.  Which is very unfortunate.  Is there any other Event I could use to achieve the same? I need to know when a Row is being added to the DataGrid and set it to the selectedItem.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the loaded event of the row itself? e.g. something like this

```
e.Row.Loaded += (s,_) => call_dataGrid.SelectedItem = (s as DataGridRow).DataContext;
```

Comment: This is it!!!! Thank you so much!!! Just one question, will this event cause any memory leak, since I am not unsubscribing from it?

Comment: Sorry, i am not too savvy in that matter, but i think this should not be a problem because due to virtualisation rows are detroyed and created quite often. You could make this a question of its own i suppose if it troubles you i suppose (or extract the lambda into handler and unsubscribe again in the handler itself to be save).

Comment: yeah I was thinking about creating a delegate handler as field and unsubscribe from it once loaded.

Comment: H.B. I came across a different problem. I wonder if you have an idea. Once I add a row, it works as expected. However if I delete one row, then try to add a new one, the Load doesn't trigger anymore. Because the DataGridRow has already been added to the visual tree, even though its not being shown anymore. If I add a second row then the Load triggers again and life is good. Any idea which other event I could utilize in case of a previous deletion? Many Thanks

Comment: @Kave: Did you unsubscribe from the event? If you did, does this also happen if you do not unsubscribe?

Comment: yes I have. After a lot of search and try. I gave up and downloaded the trial of Telerik datagrid.  I have replaced it and it works like a charm. I don;t even have to do this.  It was a bug of the MS datagrid in first place.  A pity MS gave up on updating these toolkits. I really like them.